# Passing Values between two components in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass values from one component to other components, so far i have refereed some tuts and created my code but still facing issue.

I have following code in my SelectComponent.ts

```
    export class SelectComponent implements OnInit {
 user: LoginUser
 selectLicences = [
  { name: 'Control', id: 1, isChecked: false, quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'Complete', id: 2, isChecked: false, quantity: 1 },
 ]

ControlQuantity=10
CompleteQuantity=20
```

i want to access ControlQuantity and CompleteQuanitiy in my other "buyerComponent"

here is buyerComponent.ts

```
    export class BuyerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy,AfterViewInit {​
@ViewChild('selectProducts', {​ read: SelectComponent, static: false }​)
selectProducts: SelectComponent

CompleteQuantity:number
ControlQuantity:number
ngOnInit() {
    this.CompleteQuantity=this.selectProducts.CompleteQuantity
    this.ControlQuantity=this.selectProducts.ControlQuantitity
}
}
```

stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-umje3g?

Comment: What is `selectProducts`?, what is the relationship between the components?, Please refer [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I317BhehZKM&ab_channel=Fireship) you will get idea

Comment: i have added complete BuyerComponent

Comment: Please add HTML too.

Comment: Try using [@Input](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs) on your child components. Avoid the use of `@ViewChild` as much as possible. It's not fit for unit-testing

Comment: @sonu2007 I am assuming you need to change `static` to `true`.

Comment: And you'll need to use [A two-way binding](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding) so for the child components add an `@Input() public quantity: number;` and an `@Output() public quantityChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();`

Comment: @Sameer - There is no html code, just need to use passed value in a function.

Comment: @Pieterjan Tried already but not working

Comment: @Sameer "static to true" also not working to get values

Comment: @sonu2007 `@ViewChild` is used to get element/component reference from template/HTML. As you said you don't have any HTML then `@ViewChild` has no use in your case, go with the service approach.

Comment: @Sameer oh ok there is no other way? i am not allowed to use "services'

Comment: If you don't have any relationship between components then service is the only way, @SomerandomITboy explained it very well.

Comment: Do not let your one component invadate and access internal matters of the other component. Better way, without services, would be to have a parent component which acts as a mediator. Component A emits an event which is listened and passed on to Component B. @ Input and @ output are your friends here.

https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-55uopx?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @Pieterjan, i tried by referring your code, getting error "Getter and setter accessors do not agree in visibility."

Comment: Yes the setter should be public as well `@Input() public set controlQuantity`. I updated the StackBlitz

Comment: @Pieterjan here is my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-umje3g?

Comment: @Sameer May be here you can clear idea about my coding. stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-umje3g?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the official documentation.
https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-child-component

You can pass data to your child component via @Input() decorator.

```
export class buyerComponent implements OnInit{
    @Input() CompleteQuantity:number
    @Input() ControlQuantity:number
    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.CompleteQuantity=this.selectProducts.CompleteQuantity
        this.ControlQuantity=this.selectProducts.ControlQuantitity
    }
}
```

In your HTML page, you can pass data via the child component's selector tag.

**Update: After seeing the code.**

- In AppModule, remove the BuyerComponent and Products components from Import and add them to the declaration array.
- In Buyer.component.html the tag is incorrect. Correct tag is
  "app-products" instead of "app-select-products".
- Add these as @Input() in the products component class

  ```
       @Input() CompleteQuantity:number
       @Input() ControlQuantity:number
  ```
- Rename the existing Output() variables to another name in the products.component.ts class.

Comment: core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:4002 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'ControlQuantity' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ControlQuantity' of undefined
    at e.<anonymous> (buyer.component.ts:1418)
    at tslib.es6.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:100

Comment: @sonu2007 is it possible for you to share the code repo. It seems something is not right in your code. Either Github or Stackbliz would be great.

Comment: here you go stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-umje3g?

Comment: @sonu2007 Many things are incorrect in the code. I have updated my answer based on that.

Answer (score 1):

You have two alternatives:

1. You can use a singleton service:

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class SharedService {
  sharedValue = 1
}
```

```js
@Component({…})
export class Component1 implements OnInit {
  public get prop(): number {
    return this.service.sharedValue;
  }
  constructor(private service: SharedService) { }
}
```

```js
@Component({…})
export class Component2 implements OnInit {
  public get prop(): number {
    return this.service.sharedValue;
  }
  constructor(private service: SharedService) { }
}
```

2. You have to use the parent component as a data-bridge

**The parent (bridge component)**

Note that the parent is not doing a lot of stuff but providing bindings between the shared data between children.

```html
<div>
  <app-child1 
    [value]="value"
    (valueUpdated)="onChangeValueFromChildren($event)">
  </app-child1>
  <app-child2 
    [value]="value"
    (valueUpdated)="onChangeValueFromChildren($event)">
  </app-child2>
</div>
```

```js
@Component({…})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  value = 2
  
  onChangeValueFromChildren(newValue: number) { 
    this.value = newValue
  }
}
```

Any of the children components

```js
@Component({…})
export class Child1 implements OnInit {

  @Output valueUpdated = new EventEmitter<number>();
  
  onClick() { 
     this.valueUpdated.next(Math.random())
  }
}
```

Comment: I use the service approach at work and so far it works fine, there isn't too much hassle required to operate it

Comment: @some-random-IT-boy : Thank you but not pro in angular just started with it so not sure where to add "@Injectable......"

Comment: You should use the `angular-cli` to generate your service by doing something like:

`ng generate service {the service name here}`

Comment: If you are referring to add code to "services" than i asked to do without using "services"

Comment: I can't find where you stated that you specified you didn't want to use a service. In any case you have the two alternatives in my answer: The first one is using services (which does the thing `@Injectable` thing; if you don't want it then feel free to skip it!). What you have left is the "using a parent component" as a data-bridge method

Comment: in my initial question you can see i am using 2nd method which is some how not working

Comment: You're running the binding **once** on the `ngOnInit` function. Please use the framework's builtin data-binding utilities to avoid problems like this one.

Comment: @SomerandomITboy i have added my code stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-umje3g?